# Eclipse ADT not generating MainActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am having an immensely frustrating issue with Eclipse and the ADT after updating all the SDK's, API's and Support Libraries for Android this week.

Ever since updating everything I am unable to properly create an Android Project in Eclipse. It does not generate the MainActivity.java or the main_layout.xml files at all. I have read through most of the other posts regarding this and the fixes they suggest don't seem to work. I have tried looking for the updated software by going to:

Help --> Check for updates (Everything is up-to-date).

I have also tried the manual way by going to:

Help --> Install New Software and inputting https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

It still says I have the latest version of the ADT.

I have also tried reinstalling the ADT plugin as well, but to not avail.

Trying to create an Activity after project creation also does not work.

Versions of software that I am running:

Android SDK Tools 24.0.1

Android API 1.5 up to and including API 5.0.1

Eclipse: Luna Service Release 1(4.4.1)

ADT Plugin Not sure

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADT and SDK Tools must be compatible. The latest ADT version is "ADT 23.0.4". And the corresponding SDK Tools version is 23.0.5. You have updated your SDK Tools version to 24.0.1, but there are no ADT version can support. So you should roolback to the SDK Tool version 23.0.5. 
Here is the link:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-windows.zip

Answer (score 0):

Add an **Empty Activity**, instead of Blank Activity. This will generate `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I was hoping there would be another way as I would have loved to use the DrawerLayout Template which is also not working at the moment :/

Comment: I know, and so far as I understand, google is concentrating efforts on Android Studio, and not on ADT. Did the use of `Empty Activity` work for you, to get the basic template in place?

Comment: Yes that did work atleast thank you :). Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Java version? You didn't mention about it. Please check it, it should be Java 7 for Android 5.0. If you have Java 7 then check eclipse.ini file. If it refers to Java 6 then change here also to Java 7.

Comment: Hi there, I am using the jdk 8u25. I am not sure if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Google fixed this issue and below link may help you.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82393

Comment: Thank you so much! I am so happy that they fixed it :).